# Disable source button upon click with actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I am working on a GUI java program for class where there are 10 numbered buttons in a grid layout. The user is trying to guess a 3 digit number where each digit is unique. When they click a number the corresponding number should be stored as one of the digits in the guess and then the button should be disabled. This is done in the actionPerformed method.

My problem is how to tell which button is disabled.

Currently I am trying to successfully read the value and disable the button for one digit and my code looks like this:

```
private class NumberListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent click){
        Object source = click.getSource();
        keyTry1 = getButtonNumber(source);
        source.setEnabled(false);  //error
    }
```

However at the line I marked error NetBeans complains that source has no method setEnabled, presumably because in the method it is declared as type Object.  However if I try to declare it as JButton I cannot use click.getsource();

I know I could go the brute force approach and have a long string of if/else statements or even another method which disables the button based on the number it represents, but I was wondering if there is a way to access source as a JButton, since it obviously is referencing a JButton.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`source` is an `Object` and does not have an `setEnabled` method, so it makes no sense to the compiler to allow you to make such a call.  You need to first case the instance of `source` to it's appropriate class type.

Assuming you can guarantee that the source of the action is the button, you can use something like...

```
((JButton)click.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
```

If you can't guarantee that source is `JButton`, but might be component of some kind, you might even be able to use something like...

```
((Component)click.getSource()).setEnabled(false);
```

If you can't guarantee that, then you need to make appropriate checks (which you should do anyway)...

```
Object source = click.getSource();
if (source instanceof JButton) {
    ((JButton)source).setEnabled(false);
}
```

This concept is an example of [Polymorphism](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html), where one instance of an `Object` can act like one it's parents

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had conceptually thought of the last one but didn't know about the instanceof keyword. That is the one I will implement, thanks!

Comment: @VictoriaPotvin Yep, `instanceof` doesn't appear much in the docs, but is vital...